# Unable to Set Up Continuous Deployment in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment, azure-git-deployment

Looking at the docs, it would appear that this would be super simple...perhaps it's something with my Azure Configuration. I'm simply setting up a demo project in Azure (which will be a Node app). I set up a Web App (have tried standard, basic, and free levels) and try to follow the instructions here which seem very straightforward.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/

But when I go to "All Settings" on my web app, there is no "Continuous deployment" option under the Publishing settings.

[image: Publishing Commands]

So I thought that perhaps I needed to set my deployment credentials. When I go to Deployment Credentials, it states that I need to create a deployment username and password. But even when I enter credentials that satisfy the requirements, the Save button is never enabled!

[image: Set Deployment Credentials]

Any ideas on what is going on here would be greatly appreciated. I though perhaps it was some kind of regional limitation, but that seems unlikely as I've tried both West and SouthCentral regions. I'm convinced I'm doing something obviously dumb and just missing it.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418485/unable-to-set-up-continuous-deployment-in-azure. It was not resolved, but you should follow developments there.

Comment: I verify that the Continuous Deployment option appear under Publish Setting for my web app hosted in North Europe. I didn't need to do anything for it to appear

Comment: @DavidEbbo Lol you linked back to my same issue :)

Comment: Sorry about that :) Here is what I meant to link to: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dd97e6c9-e0da-4cdb-809d-343a98bdbdd4/coadministrators-cannot-enable-continuous-deployment-option-not-available-settings-tile-errors?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just encounter the same issue, no Continuous Deployment option and cannot save deployment credentials. I just switch back to classic portal and set it from there(click the app > go to **dashboard** > **quick glance** > **Set up deployment from source control**). After setting up and then I switch back to the new portal and the option appears. Really weird issue.

Comment: agreed, I noticed that I switched to classic mode and it was there...then when I switched back to the "new" mode...it was still present.

Comment: When I looked in the classic mode, the option wasn't there either. But just adding the web hook manually in github worked, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Not much to say...I basically deleted and totally cleaned up everything from Azure and started over and miraculously the 3rd or 4th time, the option just appeared....  Not very reassuring...no idea what altered the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, but just copy paste deployment hook (Settings/Deployment Source) and add it to the github repository webhooks and it worked.

Comment: Hi, can you please help us debug this issue? It would be a great help if you could reproduce this bug and share your session Id. You can get the session Id by going hitting Ctrl+Alt+A in the portal, scrolling to the bottom of the pop-up and copy the sessionId.   Also, if you like you can post this issue on the msdn forums at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview where our portal devs can talk to you directly